# Debugging Javascript in either Chrome or Firefox seems to cause a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, firefox

I am trying to debug some javascript/jquery in Chrome. I have opened the dev tools and have set a break point within the script.

When I execute the page, the break point is hit as expected. If I then either press F10 to debug by line or just press F5 to continue, the code executes.

If I am using F10 to step through, the data appears in the table, then disappears after what looks like a page refresh. *The console does not report any errors.*

If I run the page without the break points, the data is displayed in the table correctly, but now the refresh does not happen.

Is this by design?

I have also trying the site in FireFox as well and get the same results.

Comment: I thought it's F8 to continue and F5 is indeed refresh.

Comment: Yep, stupid me.....thanks for that....I knew it was something simple.

Comment: haha it happens :D